# Why can't the floating point types compare by using memcmp() function?

Tags: c

```
bool floatcmp(const float a, const float b)
{
    const void *p = (void*)&a;
    const void *q = (void*)&b;
    if (memcmp(p, q, sizeof(float)) == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

The example code is above, the man page says `memcmp(x,y)==0` does not imply that `x==y` and floating point types often have a value called NaN (‘not a number’) with the property that NaN==NaN is false.
But I change the type to void* and I think the compiler doesn't know `a` is a float number.

Comment: Have you read and understood [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)? It is required reading.

Comment: **Why are you asking?** Please *edit your question* to give more context and some motivations!  If you want to `qsort` some array of `float` your `floatcmp` is *very* wrong. Also, pleas read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Here is a good read:- http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Comment: When you use `memcmp` you do an exact and *bitwise* comparison, i.e. all the bits in both `a` and `b` has to be *exactly* the same. Floating point numbers are often not that exact, especially lower-precision types such as `float`. And of course you have things like some special values like NaN of which there are different types and different bit-pattern.

Comment: Essentially beause the floating point format permits multiple ways to represent the same number. An analogy is I can write this 1x10^3 and this 10x10^2 but they are the same number.

Comment: It just checks if the bits are the same.  Doesn't say much about whether the value is different when the bits are not the same.  There two zeros, many NaNs.  Not unlike a struct, you can't use memcmp() on them either.  Or a string, a utf-8 encoded string will always mismatch a utf-32 encoded string even though the text is the same.  Or an integer, a two's complement encoded negative value doesn't match a one's complement encoded value.  Not like you're very likely to run into that one :)

Comment: @sashang I don't understand your comment.  If the float is [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) compliant then the mantissa is between 1 and 2, and there aren't multiple ways analagous to your example to represent a float.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why do you think somehow tricking the compiler helps write better code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be compared by `memcmp()` -- HOWEVER that comparison is a byte-by-byte comparison, which has **no** relationship to the numerical interpretation of those bytes.  As long as all the values are non-special (the various flavors of Inf/NaN etc) and normalized, it should be a reliable test for ***exact*** equality, but there is no guarantee of that, nor is there any guarantee that it's any faster than a normal exact equality test `a == b` (which by the way has the same concerns about most fractional numbers not being exactly representable in floating point) -- so two numbers that ought to be equal aren't represented that way by their floating point approximations.

EDIT: As an aside, it seems to me that sorting might be the one place that an exact comparison might be relevant for floating point numbers -- if you tell qsort that the numbers are 'equal' in the '*well their difference is less than 2e*' sense, then sorting will put them in some undetermined order, so it seems like the order given by an exact equality test ought to be as good as any other order.

Comment: In fact, of all the “special” values, only NaNs and zeroes are truly exceptions to the rule that floats can be compared with `memcmp`. There is only one representation of `+inf`, and only one for `-inf`. Each denormal has only one representation too, but `+0.0` and `-0.0` are conceptually the same, and compare equal for IEEE 754 equality, but have different representations.

Comment: Yes, I was probably overly cautious in that remark.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq Agree IEEE 754 binary encodings. Does your comment also apply to [IEEE 754 decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_formats) encodings?  Thought there were potential redundant codes there too.

Comment: Although somewhat alluded, note that `double a,b; ... if (a==b)` is always false is `a` or `b` is Nan (Not-a-number) even if `a` and `b` have the same bit pattern.

Comment: @chux Yes, decimal encodings are more messy. My comment applied to binary floating-point.

Answer (score 4):

For IEEE 754 binary floating point there are two important cases where a bit by bit equality comparison will produce different results from a floating point equality comparison.

The first and probably most important is zero. IEEE 754 has representations for both positive zero and negative zero. These will compare equal in a floating point comparison but unequal in a bitwise comparison.

The second is NaNs, comparisions involving NaNs, even equality to another identical NaN are always false, but under bitwise comparison two identical NaNs will compare the same.