# Generic quicksort not working

Tags: c, pointers, quicksort

I'm trying to make a generic quicksort function, and I fail to understand what's wrong with what I'm doing, because it's not working properly.
Here is my code:

```
typedef bool (*CmpFunction)(void*, void*);

void swap(void *c1, void *c2)
{
    assert(c1 && c2);
  int c = *(int*)c1;
  *(int*)c1 = *(int*)c2;
  *(int*)c2 = c;
}

void quick_sort(void* a, int n, CmpFunction swap)
{
   int p, b = 1, t = n - 1;
   if (n < 2)
      return;
   swap((char*)a, (char*)a+n/2);
   p = *(int*)a;
   while(b <= t) {
      while(t >= b && (char*)a + t >= p )
         t--;
      while(b <= t && (char*)a + b < p)
         b++;
      if ( b < t)
         swap((char*)a+(b++), (char*)a+(t--));
   }
   swap((char*)a, (char*)a+t);
   quick_sort(a, t, swap);
   n=n-t-1;
   quick_sort(a + t + 1, n, swap);
}
```

While the original quicksort function, without me trying to make it generic is:

```
void quick_sort(int a[], int n)
{
   int p, b = 1, t = n - 1;
   if (n < 2)
      return;
   swap(&a[0], &a[n/2]);
   p = a[0];
   while(b <= t) {
      while(t >= b && a[t] >= p )
         t--;
      while(b <= t && a[b] < p)
         b++; 
      if ( b < t) 
         swap(&a[b++], &a[t--]);
   }
   swap(&a[0], &a[t]);
   quick_sort(a, t);
   n=n-t-1;
   quick_sort(a + t + 1, n);
}

void swap(int *c1, int *c2)
    {
      int c = *c1;
      *c1 = *c2;
      *c2 = c;
    }
```

I'm using this main():

```
int main(){

    char b[] = {'a','t','b','c','y','s'};
    int c[] = {1,4,6,3,5,7};
    quick_sort(c, 6, &swap);

    for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf("%d | ", c[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Now we all agree that the output should be:

```
1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

which is indeed what I get when running the NOT generic function.
When I run my generic(upper) function I get basically trash.

You all have any ideas where I'm wrong? :)

Comment: `(char*)a+n/2`. That will not give you what you want. It will do pointer arithmetic using `char *` but the arithmetic needs to operate on `int *`.

Comment: You passed in `&swap` as your comparison function. You also failed to define what CmpFunction is. And you have compiler warnings. And a generic function either needs to work on an array of pointers, or it needs to know what the type of the array elements are.

Comment: @kaylum I have tried chaning all the (int*) to (char*). Still not working :(

Comment: @Schwern God, my bad! Edited it!

Comment: @DanBreak You also never make use of `compare`. It would be easier to answer if you pulled the code all together into a minimal, complete example.

Comment: @DanBreak A comparison function does not return `bool`, it returns `< 0` for `a < b`, `0` for `a == b`, and `> 0` for `a > b`. Just like [`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strcmp.htm). This allows a numeric comparison function to be just `return a - b`

Comment: @Schwern I don't think the fact it's bool affects my output, though. By the way, edited the code again, I changed 'compare' to 'swap'

Comment: @DanBreak If you really want to do it, go read about [pointer arithmetics](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm). Such a function will (in C) require you to let it know the operands size.

Comment: Your `swap` function can't be passed to the `swap` variable. It's very likely that's part of the issue.

Comment: @DanBreak A generic sorting function needs a comparison function else it doesn't know how to compare the generic values. Swapping pointers it can handle. This all goes back to the point that a generic function in C needs to act on pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious issue: Your input data is an int array, typecasted into a void * pointer, then forced into a char * pointer:

```
swap((char*)a, (char*)a+n/2);
```

Here you force that into a char * pointer, and jumping n/2 into it.
char * is an array of 1 byte size elements
int * is an array of 2, 4 or 8 byte size elements depending on compiler/OS/CPU.

So char *a +1, void give you the second byte of the first element of the initial array.

Comment: I have changed it to this: swap((int*)a, (int*)a+n/2); Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

[`qsort`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) is a generic sorting function. You give it an array, the size of the elements in the array, the number of elements, and a comparison function.

```
typedef int(*compare)(const void*, const void*);

void quicksort(void *base, size_t num_elements, size_t width, compare *cmp);
```

To move through the array the sorting function needs to know the width of each element so it can do the pointer arithmetic correctly. An array of `char` will be 1 byte per element. An array of `int` is probably 4 bytes. `double` will be 8. `base[4]` of a `char` array is `base + 4*1`, but it's `base + 4*4` for an `int` array. Ultimately `base[n]` is `base + (n * width)`.

To avoid making assumptions about the data in the elements, or how you want them sorted, the `compare` is used to compare elements for sorting. It returns `< 0` if `a < b`, `0` if `a == b` and `> 0` if `a > b`. This allows it to be as simple as `return a - b` for most numbers.

An example function for comparing integers:

```
int cmp_int(const void* _a, const void* _b) {
    /* Do the casting separately for clarity */
    int *a = (int *)_a;
    int *b = (int *)_b;

    return *a - *b;
}
```

There's no need to pass in a swap function. So long as you know the size of the elements a single swap function will serve. The one from [@HonzaRemeš' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36830166/14660) works.

```
void swap(void * a, void * b, size_t size) {
    /* Temp buffer large enough to contain an element */
    char tmp[size];

    memcpy(tmp, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, tmp, size);
}
```

With all this in mind, your function is not being given the element size (ie. `width`) so it cannot correctly move through the array. It's also unnecessarily passing in a `swap` function, but there's no need for this if you know the size of the elements. And you're lacking a proper comparison function to compare elements. Not much of a generic sort function if it can't compare things to sort them.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to do something the C language is not very appropriate for. If you want to do it, you need some background knowledge about [pointer arithmetics](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm).

Specifically, for a `T *`, where `T` is a type with size `N` (`sizeof(T) == N`),

```c
T * ptr;
ptr = (T *) 0x0100;
ptr = ptr + 1;
// ptr now has value 0x100 + N
```

That means you can't have a generic function which will operate on data arrays **without knowing the size of the array element**.

So I suggest you rewrite your `quick_sort` and `swap` functions to incorporate `size` parameters. You then cast your pointers to `char *` and use the `size` parameter to make the functions work correctly. Example `swap` function follows.

```c
void swap(void * c1, void * c2, size_t size) {
    char tmp[size]; // temporary buffer big enough to contain c1 data
    memcpy(tmp, c1, size);
    memcpy(c1, c2, size);
    memcpy(c2, tmp, size);
}
```

Modifying `quick_sort` is left as an exercise :). Remember though that when you don't know the size of your data, you must use `memcpy(dst, src, size)` instead of `dst = src`, you must use `memcmp(a1, a2, size) >= 0` instead of `a1 >= a2` and that your pointer access must be multiplied by `size` (exerpt from `quick_sort` follows):

**EDIT**: @Schwern points out in the comments why using `memcmp()` may not work. Comparing values of unknown size and format (endianness, float X int) would probably require a generic comparison function (which would likely be next to impossible to write). That takes us back to C's ill-suitedness for this task.

```c
void quick_sort(void *a, int n, size_t size) {
    char[size] p;
    int b = 1, t = n - 1;
    if(n < 2)
        return;
    // Using new swap with 'size' parameter
    swap(&a[0], &((char *)a)[n / 2 * size], size);
    // or swap((char *)a + 0, (char*)a + (n / 2 * size), size);
    memcpy(p, a, size);
    while(b <= t) {
        while(t >= b && memcmp((char *)a[t * size], p, size) >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

You can then write wrapper macros to pass the size parameter to the `quick_sort` function.

```
#define QSORT(arr, n) quick_sort((arr), (n), sizeof((arr)[0]))
```

Comment: Without passing in a comparison function, how does the sort function know how to sort things?

Comment: I already explained my downvote. Your swap function does not compare elements, it (unsurprisingly) just swaps them. There's no need to pass in a custom one. A comparison function, for example, would do things like case-insensitive character comparison.

Comment: `quick_sort` does not need to be passed a custom swap function, your example swap function will serve any array. Regardless, a generic sort function without a comparison function is not very generic. How does it compare things?

Comment: @Schwern Edited - added note about comparison using `memcmp()`

Comment: Nope, that's just a *numeric* sorting function and it's not good one. [Using `memcmp` like that is not safe for numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25808698/14660), it makes assumptions about the memory formats of numbers: big vs little endian for integers and I don't know what for floats. More importantly, it's not generic. Consider if you want to sort characters case-insensitively.